# HTML5-Builder client side javascript invoke URL does not work?

Tags: url, window.open, html5builder

New to HTML5. Client Page (javascript). I have a button I want to invoke another page in another browser tab. It doesn't do that, just reloads the same page in the same tab.

Button: Event : Onclick  >>>>

```
function BCDecisionOptionsClick(event) {
  window.open('upcsthome.php','_blank');
}
```

Also tried things like
    window.open('http://www.google.com', "My Page", "width=400,height=400");

Any advice please?
Thanks

Comment: Please show your button click or link code that invokes this function.

Comment: The Button has a function in its Events section in the OnClick event

Comment: The function name was entered correctly into the Onclick event in the Events section for the object. However the name for the Button was not the same as the name in the function (not counting "Click"). when I made the name the same, it worked OK. Learnt that Embarcadero HTML5 Builder does not work quite like Delphi which I am used to!.
Thanks for your interest Nikki9696.